# Chrome/Brave Re-prompting for HTTP Basic Auth Credentials

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, basic-authentication

When visiting my website that is protected w/ HTTP basic authentication in either Chrome or Brave the browser will re-prompt upon each page reload. Visiting the same page in either Firefox or Safari only prompts the first time then the credentials are "remembered" for the remainder of the session.

In my response I'm sending back the following header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="website"
```

How can I get Chrome / Brave to "remember" the HTTP basic auth credentials for the duration of a session?

Comment: I'm thinking that this might be a bug in Chromium but unsure how to verify / confirm.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue but we noticed a AJAX request was being made that was generating a 401. This appears to cause chrome to log the user out.

It might be worth checking dev tools to see if you see any 401/403s in the network requests.